# The expressive power of PoE over MoE

Tags: unsupervised-learning, deep-learning

I am reading Hinton's paper "Training Products of Experts by Minimizing Contrastive Divergence" about training PoE. There is an explanation of PoE's expressiveness, which stats "because the posterior distribution cannot be sharper than the individual
models in the mixture and the individual models must be broadly tuned to
allow them to cover the 35-dimensional manifold". I can understand the first half but I don't quite understand the second half: "the individual models must be broadly tuned to
allow them to cover the 35-dimensional manifold". Is it possible that one individual model in MoE is sharp at some point while other models be small at the same point? If it is possible, this will make the posterior be very sharp at that point.

Comment: My understanding is that you can fit *any* distribution arbitrarily well if you include enough mixture components.  The argument I've seen from deep learning folks in favor of products over mixtures is that it can take a lot more mixture components to fit the kinds of distributions they're interested in than it would take with products.  I'll keep looking for a more detailed version of the argument to post here.

Comment: Okay, I've thought about it some more, and I know how to make the argument for products over mixtures when the distributions being added or multiplied together are discrete, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the continuous case Hinton is talking about in the paper you referenced.  Would you still like for me to give it a shot?

Comment: Could you explain that in detail? It could be inspiring if you can explain that in discrete cases.